Newton-Raphson on Cox PH
I am currently working on my research, namely comparing the conventional optimization method, namely Newton-Raphson, in estimating Coxph parameters with the SGD optimization method.  What if I want to use Newton Raphson as an optimizer on Coxph?  Please help me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to the site Dion! Can you by any chance provide us with easy to use code we could work with showing us what you want, or maybe some mathematical formulations describing exactly what it is you'd like help with? Are you asking about how one does Newton-Raphson in general?
